# highcharts gauge chart and the pane option

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, highcharts, definitelytyped

I want to create a gauge chart and was wondering about how to use the pane option.
[This demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-vu-meter) supplies an array for the pane option, but the API documentation specifies that [pane is not an array](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/pane).

I actually want to use typescript to create the gauge chart and thus rely on the typings of DefinitelyTyped for highcharts. [There](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/highcharts/index.d.ts#L5993), the pane option also cannot take an array.

I see the [typings are for highcharts 5.0.10](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/highcharts/index.d.ts#L1), but the pane option does not seem to have changed to highcharts 6.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Both options are correct. You can assign either a **single JSON configuration** to the `pane` property:

```
pane: {
 // configuration
}
```

or an **array of configuration options** for any number of panes:

```
pane: [{
   // first pane configuration
 }, {
   // second pane configuration
 }
]
```

If the above array contains only one element it behaves exactly the same as a single JSON configuration (first listing).

The same rule applies to axes in Highcharts (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis).